# Copy data from sheet 1 to first empty row sheet 2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I want to make a script for my google spreadsheet that copy a range of data from sheet1 to the last empty row in Sheet2 ( column a).
I get this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Errors should be added as text not as image. Anyway, it looks that the error was caused by a typo. P.S. This question was re-floated due to question posted as an answer that now is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

#### Copy Active Range to bottom of sheet 2

```
function copy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();//you select the range before running the script
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```